# Resizing two cards with different contents at the same rate with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to design an app using bootstrap. The idea of the following code is to create 3 rows inside a container, where the first one will have 2 columns each one with a card.
In the first card (top left) I want to have 2 images side by side, but preserving the aspect ratio of each image. In the second column I want a table. The code below can do this for large resolutions. However, when I resize it I see that the card doesn't shrink at the same rate, making the two cards with different heights.
I want to make sure the cards shrink or increase in size at the same rate, so that the cards are always the same size. Also I want the table to have a vertical scroll when the height of the card reaches a certain value.
How can i do this?

```css
table.table>tbody>tr>td {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
  border: none !important;
  border-spacing: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Start your code here -->

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-cols-2">
      <div class="col-7">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <table id="stream_table" class="table">
              <tbody id="stream_body">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <!--<label id="cameralabel1" style="background-color:black;width:49.4%;visibility:hidden; height:3%; font-size:60%; position:absolute;z-index:1000;top:0%;left:0%;color:whitesmoke;text-align:center;margin:auto;" class="card-title card-title-dash">Stream</label>-->
                    <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">

                      <img id="stream_id1" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/1920/1080" title="" data-bind="attr: { title: tt9 }" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; position:absolute;visibility: visible;object-fit: fill;" alt="">
                      <!--src="vd"-->
                      <img id="stream_idnv1" title="" data-bind="attr: { title: tt10 }" src="../static/img/novideo.png" class="video" style="transform: scale(1.25,1);position: absolute; visibility: hidden; object-fit: fill; top: 0%; width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 0.3;"
                        alt="">
                      <!--src="vd"-->
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the ratio of the box, you should use the fixed height I prefer to use the `vh-100` class name, and for scrolling when content is `overflow` you can use the `overflow` property I tested your code and I think this code helps you:

```css
table.table>tbody>tr>td {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    border: none !important;
    border-spacing: 0 !important;
}

.card-body {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Start your code here -->

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row row-cols-2">
            <div class="col-7">
                <div class="card vh-100">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <table id="stream_table" class="table">
                            <tbody id="stream_body">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <!--<label id="cameralabel1" style="background-color:black;width:49.4%;visibility:hidden; height:3%; font-size:60%; position:absolute;z-index:1000;top:0%;left:0%;color:whitesmoke;text-align:center;margin:auto;" class="card-title card-title-dash">Stream</label>-->
                                        <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">

                                            <img id="stream_id1" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/1920/1080" title="" data-bind="attr: { title: tt9 }" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; position:absolute;visibility: visible;object-fit: fill;" alt="">
                                            <!--src="vd"-->
                                            <img id="stream_idnv1" title=""  data-bind="attr: { title: tt10 }" src="../static/img/novideo.png" class="video" style="transform: scale(1.25,1);position: absolute; visibility: hidden; object-fit: fill; top: 0%; width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 0.3;" alt="">
                                            <!--src="vd"-->
                                        </div>


                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
                                            <img id="stream_id2" title=""  data-bind="attr: { title: tt12 }" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/1920/1080" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; position: absolute; visibility: visible; object-fit: fill;" alt="" />
                                            <!--src="vd{{ vd_id }}"-->
                                            <img id="stream_idnv2"  title=""  data-bind="attr: { title: tt13 }" src="../static/img/novideo.png" class="video" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; object-fit: fill; top: 0%; width: 50%; height: 100%; opacity: 0.3;" alt="" />
                                            <!--src="vd{{ vd_id }}"-->
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div class="form-check form-switch">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkbox input</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <div class="card vh-100">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                                        <th scope="col">First</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                                        <td>Mark</td>
                                        <td>Otto</td>
                                        <td>@mdo</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">2</th>
                                        <td>Jacob</td>
                                        <td>Thornton</td>
                                        <td>@fat</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">3</th>
                                        <td>Larry</td>
                                        <td>the Bird</td>
                                        <td>@twitter</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">3</th>
                                        <td>Larry</td>
                                        <td>the Bird</td>
                                        <td>@twitter</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">3</th>
                                        <td>Larry</td>
                                        <td>the Bird</td>
                                        <td>@twitter</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">3</th>
                                        <td>Larry</td>
                                        <td>the Bird</td>
                                        <td>@twitter</td>
                                    </tr>



                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">

                One of three columns
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                One of three columns
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- End your code here -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately this solution is not what I want. When I tested the code, I saw that the cards are stretched to the bottom of the display. I want three rows on the display area. I want the cards in the top row to be "syncronized", which means as I'm resizing the window they need to stretch or shrink at the same rate, so that both have always the same height.

Comment: you can change vh-100 to fix size like below `style="height:200px"`

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way shrinking the page and all the elements to maintain the same aspect ratio. It turns out I need to put the table inside a cell of another table. The table-child needs to be inside a div (). This way, whenever I shrink the page, the elements remain in the same place, but smaller.

Comment: Please add more information about the answer and format code properly.